Как запускать dotnet через кнопку в VSCode
Есть проект на C#, но мне приходится запускать его через консоль dotnet run. Как можно это сделать через кнопку или сочитание клавиш ?


https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490495/13754729

@Dev18 Сложно то как. Неужели нет попроще рецепта? )

Файлы launch.json и tasks.json заполняются автоматически при включенном расширении c#. Если этого не произошло перезагрузи окно VSCode и согласись с предложением(справа внизу кликни Да) указанным в этом руководстве. Дальше кроме кнопки F5 больше ничего не нужно.

@AlexanderLonberg у меня нет файлов launch.json и tasks.json.

@AslanPAPA Эти файлы будут созданы автоматически в каталоге .vscode, и каталог так же будет автоматом создан.

@AlexanderLonberg у меня как раз таки не создается этот каталог

@AslanPAPA оставил тебе копии в ответе. И попробуй создать новый проект, откуда уже просто копируй с изменениями имени проекта.

Дополнение для коммента: Сделал для тебя файлы с версией NET 8.
Создай, если еще нет, каталог в корне .vscode и положи туда два файла.
Замени на свое имя проекта соответствующие <PROJECT>
.vscode/launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
      // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
      // For further information visit https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/debugger-launchjson.md
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net8.0/<PROJECT>.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "stopAtEntry": false
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach"
    }
  ]
}


.vscode/tasks.json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "${workspaceFolder}/<PROJECT>.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary;ForceNoAlign"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "publish",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "publish",
        "${workspaceFolder}/<PROJECT>.csproj",
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary;ForceNoAlign"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
      "label": "watch",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "watch",
        "run",
        "--project",
        "${workspaceFolder}/<PROJECT>.csproj"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}

PS: надо было новый проект создать и попробовать все сначала именно по документации. Должно работать, либо у тебя что-то не то с расширениями, возможно конфликтуют. Вот примерно как  должно получиться и все это запускается клавишей F5 или кнопкой из раздела Run And Debug.

PS: Изменяй задачи как угодно и смотри в консоль - все эти аргументы ты должен был видеть в книжках dotnet run --project ...
{
      "label": "run",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "run",
        "--project",
        "${workspaceFolder}/<PROJECT>.csproj"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }


Смотрите, там получается и дебаг и запуск поэтому он долго запускается ?

@AslanPAPA Нет не получается. Автоматом генерируются самые популярные настройки и дебагер использует только один Task-build. Кроме build есть задача watch. И если ты наберешь F1->Run Task->watch, то увидишь в консоли свою команду dotnet watch run --project ... без дебагера. Копируешь этот раздел, удаляешь первый аргумент watch и переименовываешь в, например, "label":"run", если тебе нужен один run. Тебе предложили шаблоны, которые можно копировать и изменять на свое усмотрение(выше пример). А для кнопок установи любой TaskRunner-плагин, который и будет запускать твои задачи.

Спасибо помогли!
